# control idle time external page

Tags: javascript, html

I made an simple web page that reference an external page. Are there way to rollback to my web page when the external page to stay idle ?

example my internal page

```
<button class="button"> <a href = "https://www.searchsite.com"> Answer</button>
```

example my control page

```
     <script language = "JavaScript">
        location.href  = "C:../mypage.html";
        setTimeout("document.location = 'C:..mypage.html'",1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending them to the page, where you have no control, load that page in an iframe. The iframe can be either created when the page loads (if the url is static) and just hidden with css or you can create the iframe with javascript when they click. Then use javascrpit to set the iframe size to the full width and height of the browser window. It will looks like the other site but you still have control.

In the event they resize the browser you may need to have a resize event listener. Also you may wish to modify the browser history so if they hit back they go back to your site.

Then when the timeout limit is reached you can use the setTimeout to just hide or remove the iframe.

Do note that some websites prevent the page from loading in an iframe. So test that first. If they don't allow it things get quite a bit more complicated you would need to use php to grab their pages html, css and javascript, make the changes you need, and then load it in your site.

Based on the url, in your code sample, I must assume you wanting to load some search engines page, many of them have API's you could use to incorporate their search functionality into your site.